# Why .* operator can not be overloaded in c++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I found out few of the post here discussing about operator overloading and operators which can not be overloaded in c++ like `.` `::` `.*`  `sizeof` etc . But I could not find out exact details or reason about why should `.*` be avoided ? Few of you might vote it as duplicate but I would be more than happy if I get details on those link about what I want :)

Comment: It's for the same reason `operator .` can't be overloaded.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas you mean to say we can overload ->* so we should not be able to overload .* ?

Comment: @Ritesh: I don't think you can infer that from what Nicol stated. He just said that the underlying reason not to allow `operator.` overloads and `operator.*` overloads is the same. There is no link from that to `operator->*` (at least not directly)

Comment: Think for a moment how overloading `.` would work. `A.b` would become `A.operator.().b` would become `A.operator.().operator.().b` would become...

Comment: @BoBTFish The recursion would stop as soon as `operator().` returned a reference to a different type.  Which is, of course, the whole point; if I want a reference to the same type, I don't need an overload.

Comment: why different operators can not be overloaded:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077322/why-operator-can-not-be-overloaded-in-c

Comment: @NicolBolas `operator.` has one argument, `operator.*` has two.

Comment: @BoBTFish `a->b` becomes `a.operator->()->b` becomes `a.operator->().operator->()->b` ... until the result doesn't allow overloading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Horse's mouth](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#overload-dot):

> Operator `.` (dot) could in principle be overloaded using the same technique as used for ->. However, doing so can lead to questions about whether an operation is meant for the object overloading `.` or an object referred to by `.` For example:

```
class Y {
public:
    void f();
    // ...
};

class X {   // assume that you can overload .
    Y* p;
    Y& operator.() { return *p; }
    void f();
    // ...
};

void g(X& x)
{
    x.f();  // X::f or Y::f or error?
}
```

> **This problem can be solved in several ways. At the time of standardization, it was not obvious which way would be best.**

AFAIU the same reasoning applies for `.*`

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to understand, if you go through the internal mechanism of operator function invocation.

Say a class `Complex` can have two members; `r` for the real part and `i` for the imaginary part. For instance:

```
Complex C1(10,20),C2(10,2) // we assume there is an already a two argument constructor within class.
```

Now if you write `C1+C2` as a statement, the compiler tries to find the overloaded version of the `+` operator on complex numbers. If you overload the `+` operator, so `C1+C2` is internally translated as `c1.operator+(c2)`.

But what would you translate an overloaded `.` operator as? For instance:

```
C1.disp()//display content of a complex object
```

Now try to come up with an internal representation of `C1.operator.(------)`. Given that this syntax would modify it's own semantic meaning, the result is hopelessly messy. For that reason overloading the `.` is not allowed.